# Could not find rake 10.0.3 in any of the sources, when working with Whenever and Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano, bundler, whenever

I'm trying to use the gem Whenever with Capistrano over my Rails app on 3.2.8, working with RVM and a gemset for that Rails version.

I'm getting the following error: **Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)**

This is the output of the error (which I logged over a file):

```
/home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:113:in `specs'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:158:in `specs_for'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:147:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/some_user/some_user/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/some_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

I did also get the error when I was using Rake 10.0.2 (I made **bundle update** and get Rake 10.0.3, and I leave it for testing). Also, I noticed that the bundler is searching over @global when I think it should search over the gemset (called @r328, and is located on /home/some_user/.rvm/gems).

.rvmrc (located inside of the project)

```
source ~/.profile
rvm use 1.9.3@r328
rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1
```

.profile

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

schedule.rb (for testing)

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"

every 1.minute do
  runner "MenuOrder.send_resume(2)"
end
```

deploy.rb

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

The output of gem list

```
actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
active_utils (1.0.5)
activeadmin (0.5.0)
activemerchant (1.29.3, 1.28.0)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (3.2.8)
arbre (1.0.1)
arel (3.0.2)
authorize-net (1.5.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bourbon (3.0.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.1)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.1)
capistrano (2.13.5)
carrierwave (0.8.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.0)
chronic (0.9.0)
cocaine (0.4.2)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
daemon_controller (1.1.0)
daemons (1.1.9)
delayed_job (3.0.4)
delayed_job_active_record (0.3.3)
devise (2.2.0, 2.1.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
fastthread (1.0.7)
formtastic (2.2.1)
has_scope (0.5.1)
highline (1.6.15)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
inherited_resources (1.3.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.4, 2.1.3)
json (1.7.6, 1.7.5)
kaminari (0.14.1)
mail (2.4.4)
meta_search (1.1.3)
mime-types (1.19)
money (5.1.0)
multi_json (1.5.0, 1.3.7, 1.3.6)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.6.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
nokogiri (1.5.6, 1.5.5)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
paperclip (3.4.0, 3.3.1)
passenger (3.9.1.beta, 3.0.19, 3.0.18)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.3, 1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-raw-upload (1.1.1, 1.1.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (10.0.3, 10.0.2, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
recaptcha (0.3.4)
responders (0.9.3)
rich (1.4.1, 1.3.1)
rmagick (2.13.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sass (3.2.5, 3.2.3, 3.2.1)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35, 0.3.34)
uglifier (1.3.0)
warden (1.2.1)
whenever (0.8.1)
```

I tried with bundle update, removing Gemfile.lock and making bundle install, uninstalling all the rake gems (10.0.3 and 10.0.2) and installing the gem with bundle install but nothing worked.

Comment: I faced the same problem. Solved!

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18096502/1524350

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did to solve the problem was a little tricky:

1. Remove all the versions of Rake
2. Remove Gemfile.lock
3. Run bundle install
4. Install Rake manually with: gem install rake --version=10.0.2

Now it is working, but for some reason it doesn't write the log file. I will fix it and post the update.

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
bundle install --path vendor/cache
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I run the command, but then in the file cron.log (which I generate from Whenever, adding it to crontab) doesn't show anything. If I remove the file, 1 minute after is generated but empty... I don't know what it could be.

Comment: This fixed the issue. But could you please explain why it fixed it and what was wrong in the first place?

Comment: An explanation for this would be useful :)

Answer (score 2):

Just a `bundle install` worked for me. I think it was because I had updated Ruby but then forgot to run bundler afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

So that's the error you get when you're running a rake task or when you're setting up a rake task to when with cron? If you think it's the whatever gem, I KNOW there has been a lot of discussion about whenever not working because Capistrano actually changed around some internals and they've been slowly fixing them, but they haven't released an update to the gem.

Run a search through their issues and see if you can find what is related to you:

https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues

Comment: I think Capistrano and Whenever are working fine, because the task is executed at the time, but the problem comes when executing the task because it doesn't find the rake gem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is actually due to **BUNDLE_PATH** overriding the rvm gemset settings and storing the downloaded files elsewhere whenever you run **bundle install**. To solve this, you can either delete your .bundle folder or remove the **BUNDLE_PATH** line from .bundle/config. Just rerun bundle install once that's done and you should be good to go!